# Where to place modules related to AI in MVCS

Tags: asp.net-mvc, artificial-intelligence, service-layer

I am bit confused, what is the right place to place the modules related to AI in an MVCS pattern ? Alongside with Model View Controller and Services folder ?

V.

Comment: There is no such thing as MVCS. Services are part of model layer. The confusion is caused by Rails-like naming convention (ASP.NET MVC was originally just another Rails clone), which mistakenly refers to [domain objects](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?DomainObject) as "models".

Comment: oh.. 
actually, many code i go through nowadays make a separate folder for "services". That made me think "services" as a 4th entity